# Android Studio (wear + mobile) app in same project

Tags: android, mobile, project

I would like my android app to work in android wear too. I'm using android studio as IDE.
So what do I do for my app to work in android wear?  Do I create another project? If so, will it share the same layouts and classes or will it be a whole other app? I mean, do I need to create two different apps for mobile and wear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use Android Studio creates a new project with two modules, `mobile and wear.` You now have a project for both your handheld and wearable apps that you can create activities, services, custom layouts, and much more in. On the handheld app, you do most of the heavy lifting, such as network communications, intensive processing, or tasks that require long amounts of user interaction. When these are done, you usually notify the wearable of the results through notifications or by syncing and sending data to the wearable.

For more details, please refer to [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html#CreateProject).

Comment: Thanks for help. Can we release only one app on playstore for both Watch & Phone?

Answer (score 1):

Select and Go with the android wear activity and in the next window showing *Configure your project*, Check the **Pair with Empty Phone App** then it will automatically configure it for android phone and wear.

Answer (score 0):

if you create a wear project, it automatically create "app" and "wear" modules. when you assemble, the wear APK gets embedded in the app APK. that's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

old) In older versions of Android Studio you could select the different platforms for which a module was required during creation of the project.

new) In the current versions of Android Studio you have to just one platform and add the modules for additional platforms after creation of the project.

old)
[image: old version of Android Studio]

new)
[image: current version of Android Studio]

Comment: But suppose you have a working Android Studio project...
How do you create a "wear" module within it?

It can be done.. using File->New Module...
But it's very messy, and fails to address the main issue that most of the source files are  shared.  I'll post a separate question.